# Jquery Ajax page reloads on submit

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem that when I submit the page (form) the submission to php mail is success but the page again reloads. Tried return true and false also preventDefault() but still the page reloads.

```
$('#frmRequest').submit(function(e){
    //$('#SUBMIT').click(function(){
    var isValidForm = true;
    $('#RequestDetailsArea').find('input:visible, textarea:visible, select:visible').each(function(){
        if( $(this).val().length == 0|| $(this).val()=='Select' ) {
            $(this).addClass('validation');
            isValidForm = false;      
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('validation'); 
            $('#ErrorRequest').addClass('hidden');           
        }
    });/* end check validation in RequestDetailsArea*/
    if (!isValidForm) {
        $('#ErrorRequest').removeClass('hidden');   
    }
    validreturn=validateForm();
    if(isValidForm && validreturn)
    {
        $('#RequestDetailsArea').find('div:hidden').each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).remove();
        });

        msg="ok";
        $.ajax({
            url:"allfields.php",
            type:"POST",
            //      dataType:"json",
            data: $("#frmRequest").serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                //alert("Form Submitted: "+ msg);
                return msg;

            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();

        //return false;
    }
});/* end of submit Function*/
```

Comment: Is your form submits immediately without validating it ?

Comment: Validation is already done through  if(isValidForm && validreturn)
in separate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have put `e.preventDefault();` inside

```
if(isValidForm && validreturn)
{
    //...
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

So I think if your condition doesn't match then the form will be submitted because the calling of method `e.preventDefault();` won't be executed. If this is the case then you can keep it out of your `if` condition, i.e,

```
$('#frmRequest').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code here
});
```

**Update:** You are using `return msg` in your `success`, that will do nothing, you can do it in this way

```
success: function(msg){
    returnValue(msg); // call the function      
}
```

and declare the `returnValue` somewhere in the script like

```
function returnValue(data)
{
    // do something with data
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `success` is being called ?

Comment: Yes the success is being called. The message get POSTED. The only thing is page reload.

Comment: Try to debug the `success` function, write `console.log(msg)` and see what you get in the console.

Comment: I actually want java script of "allfields.php" to be processed too. however, ajax by default show success ....action. I have already written code of what needs to be displayed on my ""allfields.php" page and I want to use that instead of being stuck in the same page.